# How to add a new orderer to a running network with kafka mode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm adding a new orderer to a running network in kafka mode. The prolem is that if the kafka cluster is newly built or has deleted some early data logs of the transactions, newly added orderer seems not able to get the data of blocks that generated before the orderer joins, which means the new orderer can not provide services for the network and may trigger other orderers reporting consenser error and stopping the whole orderer service in network

I've tested running newly built kafka cluster without adding orderer operarion. it turned out to be okay and the fabric network runs fine.

I am confused why the newly added orderer can't pull data from existing orderers. if OSN works like this, it will meet fatal risk to be unavailable when we move kafka cluster

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested, but I think you can just copy the files of the ledger and then the new orderer node won't have to pull all transactions from the Kafka service.

> I am confused why the newly added orderer can't pull data from
>   existing orderers. if OSN works like this, it will meet fatal risk to
>   be unavailable when we move kafka cluster

It was just not implemented. This ability exists only in Raft.